# How to edit Developer Web Server URL

Tags: asp.net, web, server

I'm working on an old ASP.NET web application build originally on top .Net 4.
Under Web Site Properties/ Developer Web Server, I am trying to edit the URL to use a different port. But it's not editable.
[image]

Thanks

I'm trying to run the application but I'm getting this error: "Unable to launch the configured Visual Studio Development Web server. Port '80' is in use. So my goal was to edit the URL to use a different port#

More Info:
In Project Menu There is no Project Properties menu Item Only "Start Options.." which gives me this popup:
[image]

Comment: _Unable to launch the configured Visual Studio Development Web server. Port '80' is in use._ It sounds like you are trying to run it from Visual Studio but there is already a web server on port 80. The simplest solution might be to stop any _existing_ web server that is already running on port 80, (i.e. IIS). Or perhaps your dev web server is incorrectly confgured to run on port 80 and you can use these steps to change it to some other inocuous port https://blog.novacare.no/how-to-change-portnumber-for-sql-express-development/

Answer (score 0):

Normally you should be able to just hit the button "Create Virtual Folder".

So, open the project settings.

Choose project setting from this menu:

[image]

Then you choose web, and you have this:

[image]

Normally, the default is to "random" offer a port number, but you can enter one into above, and then hit the "Create Virtual Directory" button in above.

So, the above web settings page is where you setup the port number/virtual directory.

Don't forget to hit the "Create Virtual Directory" button in above.

## Edit: User's project is a web site.

Ok, so there are 2 types of sites.

```
1) asp.net web site
2) asp.net web site "application"
```

This explains why the poster can't see the same options as per above screen captures.

So, close your project, and open the SLN file with note pad.

The setting you want to change will look like this:

[image]

If this project is not large, then I would consider converting the project from a asp.net "web site", to a "asp.net web site application". As my screen shot shows, the configuration options, and build options are better when your project type is an "application" as opposed to your web site.

Comment: For this project I don't have that properties menu item to chose. All I have is Menu Project/"Start Options" which has "Use default Web server" option checked.

Comment: If you have a project file (.sln), then try opening that via file-> open project.  Of course if this is not an web site application,  then you use file-> open web site and no project file exists

Comment: Yes The project is opened using .sln file.

Comment: Ok, see my edit. You have to open the .sln file directly with note pad.